# Part of speech tagging and entity recognition - python

Tags: python, azure, named-entity-recognition, part-of-speech, azure-machine-learning-service

I want to perform part of speech tagging and entity recognition in python similar to Maxent_POS_Tag_Annotator and Maxent_Entity_Annotator functions of openNLP in R.  I would prefer a code in python which takes input as textual sentence and gives output as different features- like number of "CC", number of "CD", number of "DT" etc.. CC, CD, DT are POS tags as used in Penn Treebank. So there should be 36 columns/features for POS tagging corresponding to 36 POS tags as in [Penn Treebank POS](http://www.ling.upenn.edu/courses/Fall_2003/ling001/penn_treebank_pos.html). I want to implement this on Azure ML "Execute Python Script" module and Azure ML supports python 2.7.7. I heard nltk in python may does the job, but I am a beginner on python. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at [NTLK book](http://www.nltk.org/book/ch05.html), Categorizing and Tagging Words section.

Simple example, it uses the Penn Treebank tagset:

```
from nltk.tag import pos_tag
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
pos_tag(word_tokenize("John's big idea isn't all that bad.")) 

[('John', 'NNP'),
("'s", 'POS'),
 ('big', 'JJ'),
 ('idea', 'NN'),
 ('is', 'VBZ'),
 ("n't", 'RB'),
 ('all', 'DT'),
 ('that', 'DT'),
 ('bad', 'JJ'),
 ('.', '.')]
```

Then you can use

```
from collections import defaultdict
counts = defaultdict(int)
for (word, tag) in pos_tag(word_tokenize("John's big idea isn't all that bad.")):
    counts[tag] += 1
```

to get frequencies:

```
defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {'JJ': 2, 'NN': 1, 'POS': 1, '.': 1, 'RB': 1, 'VBZ': 1, 'DT': 2, 'NNP': 1})
```

Comment: Thanks @hellpanderr. Can you pls also guide the steps how to import nltk in python? I am new on python. Windows 7 - 64 bit.

Comment: @ankur The steps for import nltk in python: 1. open a cmd window; 2. command 'cd' into the path of installed Python; 3. command 'Scripts/pip.exe install ntlk'

Comment: @PeterPan-MSFT I am using python 2.7.7. pip is not installed. It is showing error of Scripts is not recognized as internal or external command.

Comment: @PeterPan-MSFT one more related question. If I want to use just pos_tag, word_tokenize what option i should put under nltk.download(info_or_if=' ') under id?

Comment: @ankur Download pip-7.1.2.tar.gz from the page https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip, decompress it  and command 'python setup.py' to install pip.

Comment: @PeterPan-MSFTImport Error: No module named setuptools

Comment: @ankur Please create a new thread for your more related question about NTLK, the comment is not used for answer the details of programming. Thanks.